# Passing data from a ASP web form page to an Angular2 app

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I'm working on a legacy WebForms system. It is in the process of being updated to Angular 2 but his is only happening a piece at a time.

I need to get information from the legacy portion of the site(it is sitting in a form) to use in the Angular app section. So far I have looked at trying to:

1. interrogate the DOM from the APP.
2. using @Input to pass the data through.

I have also looked into setting up some kind of global event that the Angular APP can subscribe to.

I have looked and can't seem to find any thing on how this can be done/what the recommended way to do this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be better to do it by making a directive, which is recommended to access the dom, use @output to communicate with other components.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work by saving the needed data to SessionStorage. I then fire an event when it is updated.